# How to get FastCGI Documentation?

Tags: web, documentation, fastcgi

The FastCGI's website http://www.fastcgi.com/ which hosted Documentation is now pointing to something else. How can i read their documentation now?

Comment: Looks like that project has gone the way of the Dodo bird.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/) to solve your immediate need:

http://replay.web.archive.org/20090226052433/http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/overview.html

Comment: Yes thanks. What has happened to their website? any one on their mailing list.

Comment: I would guess that this is a faulty DNS configuration or something similar and that it will be back up soon(ish).